# Elephant io Undefined index : upgrades

Tags: symfony

Trying to reach ly node server with elephant io
But I fail with that error :

> In Version1X.php line 194: Notice: Undefined index: upgrades

I added the dependency to my composer and the wissembly/elephant-io is well present in my vendor.

> composer

```
    "wisembly/elephant.io": "~3.0"
```

> action

```
$client = new Client(new Version1X('http://localhost:1299/map'));
    // open connection
    $client->initialize();

    $output->writeln("update des offres");
    $offers = $this->em->getRepository('AppRefactoredBundle:app_Offer')->findAll();
    foreach($offers as $offer){
        if($offer->getUpdatedAt() < new DateTime('-2 hours')){
            $offer->setCurrentStatus(2);


            // send for server (listen) the any array
            $client->emit('timeout', ['idUser' => $offer->getProfile()]);
        }
    }
```

Here is the doc: https://github.com/mairesweb/socket.io-elephant.io/blob/master/client.php

I don't require the autoload cause I can't find it, may be this is why...but I don't know how to do that.

Thanks for help.

Comment: What your url `http://localhost:1299/map` returns ? It seems that the lib cannot decode your output.

Comment: It's a simple set of sockets roads in node :  `server.listen(1299);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
    const map = io.of('/map');`

Comment: Yes but what is the output ? Is it a valid json or something else ?

Comment: @UgoT. I don't understand what you mean there ? Output of what ?

Comment: What is returned when you hit the URL `http://localhost:1299/map` ? A blank page ? Some json ?

Comment: It's an html page I write to make some local test. But it's not really important I think the node is working already with some Rect Native clients.